# Creating a box-shadow offset without additional elements or double box-shadows

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to give a box-shadow an offset without using `:before` and `:after` (and, of course, additional elements) like this (which would cost the usage of at least one pseudo-element, and I don't want that):

```css
body {
  background: #34495e;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #3498db;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

...and without using a double box-shadow which would require the knowledge of the background-color as otherwise there would be a non-transparent gap:

```css
body {
  background: #34495e;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #3498db;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white, 0 0 0 3px #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: consider the first solution with background. Note that you can replace border with box-shadow if you want

Comment: In your second example, replace `white` in this line; `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white, 0 0 0 3px #e74c3c;` with just `currentColor` and inherit your color.

Comment: @ChrisW. currentColor consider the `color` not `background-color`

Comment: I thought he wanted to get from color, which since isn't set is transparent, must be mis interpreting no worries